# How to add data into the table in vue.js?

Tags: vue.js

I want to add the data into table when I want to.
However, I can not add the data after initializing the vue instances.

I have tried to use followings, but, still dose not update data.

・$nextTick
・$set

```
<script>
var overall = new Vue({                                                                                                                                         
  el: '#overall',                                                                                                                                               
  data: {                                                                                                                                                       
      headers:[                                                                                                                                                 
        "no","name",'gender'                                                                                                                          
      ],                                                                                                                                                        
      items: []                                                                                                                                                 
  },                                                                                                                                                              methods: {                                                                                                                                                    
    add: function(item)                                                                                                                                         
    {                                                                                                                                                           
      this.items = item;
    }
  }
});

overall.add([{no:'1',name:'Tom Tom',gender:'male'}]);
</script>

<div id="overall">
  <table>
    <thead>      <tr>
        <th  v-for="header in headers">
          {{header}}
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody >
      <tr v-if="items.length === 0">                                                                                                                                    <td>No data</td>                                                                                                                                        </tr>                                                                                                                                                           <tr v-else v-for="item in items">                                                                                                                         

        <td>{{item.no}}</td>
        <td>{{item.name}}</td>
        <td>{{item.gender}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: your `add` function is assigning an item to `this.items`,  i dont know what youre doing here.

Comment: `this.items = item;` should rather be `this.items.push(item);`

Comment: Multiple problems with the code:  1) `add` needs to `push`,  2) `tbody` `tr` needs a `v-for`, 3) `add` should be defined in Vue app's `methods` object, 4) `add` should be called in `created` lifecycle hook, not outside the app

Answer (score 1):

I think that before moving forward to the solution, you should know a couple of things:

- data is a function, it should return the component values.

```
  data: function() {
    return {
        headers: ['Nº', 'Name', 'Gender'],
        items: [{}],
    }
  },
```

- When working with arrays, there is a method to append an object to it. This method is called "push", and you should use in the following way:

```
  methods: {
    add: function(item) {
        this.items.push(item);
    }
  },
```

- When working with Vue Instance, there is one recommendation: Don't use outside its scope. You CAN use it, but you SHOULD NOT. It's a better solution to load array elements on the created or mounted events, you can read more about it on VueJS site. https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks

About the solution, I have combined what I told you, and it's working. I added the :key property to v-for elements, but the major change is on the JavaScript code:

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
  data: function() {
    return {
        headers: ['Nº', 'Name', 'Gender'],
      items: [{}],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    add: function(item) {
        this.items.push(item);
    }
  },
  mounted: function() {
    this.add({no:'1',name:'Tom Tom',gender:'male'});
    this.add({no:'2',name:'Marcos Huck',gender:'male'});
  },
  
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Then, I have another question. If we have another vue instance and I want call from that instance, what should we do?

Comment: Or, vue instance should not communicate with other instance?

Comment: No problem Leo! Your solution should use another approach for that kind of problem, avoid the usage of Vue Instances, and keep in mind that your app is a wrapper of components. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html#ad

Comment: Thanks Marcos. This is very helpful for me. So, I have to use components in my case as you told me. I will try it out today :)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is you are not updating the `Array` but completely replacing it with new one everytime you are using the `add` method.

```
add: function(item) {                                                                                                                                                           
      this.items.push(item); //change this line to push item to array instead of replacing it everytime.
    }
```

Another part which you need to fix is, instead of passing an `array` of items in `add` method, pass just the item you want to add.

```
overall.add({no:'1',name:'Tom Tom',gender:'male'}); // remove the array brackets from here
```

Below is running example:
https://jsfiddle.net/52d96oxj/

```js
var overall = new Vue({
  el: '#overall',
  data: {
    headers: [
      "no", "name", 'gender'
    ],
    items: []
  },
  methods: {
    add: function(item) {
      this.items.push(item); // push item to existing array
    }
  }
});

// Add objects, not array to the list
overall.add({ no: '1', name: 'Tom Tom', gender: 'male'});
overall.add({ no: '2', name: 'John Doe', gender: 'male'});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="overall">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th v-for="header in headers">
          {{header}}
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-if="items.length === 0">
        <td>No data</td>
      </tr>
      <tr v-else v-for="item in items">

        <td>{{item.no}}</td>
        <td>{{item.name}}</td>
        <td>{{item.gender}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. This is very helpful for me.